# Trouble deserializing JSON from Apple's iTunes Genre IDs service

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, windows-8, json.net

The JSON returned from Apple's iTunes Genre IDs service is unlike other JSON I've encountered in the past.  Because of this, I'm having trouble building the classes needed to deserialize it.

Here is an example of the JSON (I've cut it down for clarity; the full JSON can be found [here](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/genres?id=26)):

```
{
    "26": {
        "name": "Podcasts",
        "id": "26",
        "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts/id26?mt=2",
        "subgenres": {
            "1301": {
                "name": "Arts",
                "id": "1301",
                "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts/id1301?mt=2",
                "subgenres": {
                    "1306": {
                        "name": "Food",
                        "id": "1306",
                        "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-food/id1306?mt=2"
                    },
                    "1401": {
                        "name": "Literature",
                        "id": "1401",
                        "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-literature/id1401?mt=2"
                    },
                    "1402": {
                        "name": "Design",
                        "id": "1402",
                        "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-design/id1402?mt=2"
                    },
                    "1405": {
                        "name": "Performing Arts",
                        "id": "1405",
                        "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-performing-arts/id1405?mt=2"
                    },
                    "1406": {
                        "name": "Visual Arts",
                        "id": "1406",
                        "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-visual-arts/id1406?mt=2"
                    },
                    "1459": {
                        "name": "Fashion & Beauty",
                        "id": "1459",
                        "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-arts-fashion-beauty/id1459?mt=2"
                    }
                }
            },
            "1321": {
                "name": "Business",
                "id": "1321",
                "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-business/id1321?mt=2",
                "subgenres": {
                    "1410": {
                        "name": "Careers",
                        "id": "1410",
                        "url": "https: //itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-business-careers/id1410?mt=2"
                    },
                    "1412": {
                        "name": "Investing",
                        "id": "1412",
                        "url": "https: //itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-business-investing/id1412?mt=2"
                    },
                    "1413": {
                        "name": "Management&Marketing",
                        "id": "1413",
                        "url": "https: //itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-business-management/id1413?mt=2"
                    },
                    "1471": {
                        "name": "BusinessNews",
                        "id": "1471",
                        "url": "https: //itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-business-business/id1471?mt=2"
                    },
                    "1472": {
                        "name": "Shopping",
                        "id": "1472",
                        "url": "https: //itunes.apple.com/us/genre/podcasts-business-shopping/id1472?mt=2"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my classes for receiving the data:

```
public class PodcastGenreResult
{
    public PodcastGenreInfo GenreInfo { get; set; }
}

public class PodcastGenreInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string GenreName { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the deserialize call:

```
PodcastGenreResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PodcastGenreResult>(sResults);
```

where `sResults` is the JSON string.  I've confirmed that this string contains the correct data.

After this, no error is thrown, but `result.GenreInfo` is always null. I've tried other ways, but this is the closest I feel that should work. Most of the time, I use the `JsonProperty` attribute to specify what objects I want, but I can't here because that root name changes depending on what ID I'm asking for.  How can I define my classes in order to deserialize the data?

Comment: Put some Json so we get a complete picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually fairly common.  To handle an object where the keys are dynamic, you need to deserialize into a `Dictionary<string, T>` where `T` is your item class.  So in your case:

```
Dictionary<string, PodcastGenreInfo> genres = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, PodcastGenreInfo>>(sResults);
```

Notice also that the `subgenres` property of the genre object is the same way, so you would define it as a dictionary as well:

```
public class PodcastGenreInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string GenreName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("subgenres")]
    public Dictionary<string, PodcastGenreInfo> Subgenres { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a working demo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string url = "http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/genres?id=26";
            string json = client.DownloadString(url);
            var genres = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, PodcastGenreInfo>>(json);
            Dump(new PodcastGenreInfo { GenreName = "Genres", Subgenres = genres }, "");
        }
    }

    private static void Dump(PodcastGenreInfo genre, string indent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(indent + genre.GenreName);
        if (genre.Subgenres != null)
            foreach (var kvp in genre.Subgenres)
                Dump(kvp.Value, indent + "  ");
    }

    public class PodcastGenreInfo
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string GenreName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("subgenres")]
        public Dictionary<string, PodcastGenreInfo> Subgenres { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Genres
  Podcasts
    Arts
      Design
      Fashion & Beauty
      Food
      Literature
      Performing Arts
      Visual Arts
    Business
      Business News
      Careers
      Investing
      Management & Marketing
      Shopping
    Comedy
    Education
      Educational Technology
      Higher Education
      K-12
      Language Courses
      Training
    Games & Hobbies
      Automotive
      Aviation
      Hobbies
      Other Games
      Video Games
    Government & Organizations
      Local
      National
      Non-Profit
      Regional
    Health
      Alternative Health
      Fitness & Nutrition
      Self-Help
      Sexuality
    Kids & Family
    Music
    News & Politics
    Religion & Spirituality
      Buddhism
      Christianity
      Hinduism
      Islam
      Judaism
      Other
      Spirituality
    Science & Medicine
      Medicine
      Natural Sciences
      Social Sciences
    Society & Culture
      History
      Personal Journals
      Philosophy
      Places & Travel
    Sports & Recreation
      Amateur
      College & High School
      Outdoor
      Professional
    TV & Film
    Technology
      Gadgets
      Podcasting
      Software How-To
      Tech News
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. And it makes sense, too, I've just never had to use that route. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the problem is badly designed json, the genre id is used instead of a property name. The json should look like this:

```
{"genre":{"name":"Podcasts","id":"26", ...
    "subgenres":{"genre": {"name":"Arts","id":"1301","url":
```

Instead of:

```
{"26":{"name":"Podcasts","id":"26", ...
    "subgenres":{"1301":{"name":"Arts","id":"1301","url":
```

I would load the  json into a dynamic object:

```
dynamic genres = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<dynamic>(json);
```

If you wanted you could convert the dynamic object into strongly typed objects.

Comment: @brian-rogers answer worked for me, but I can see how the dynamic type would be useful in this situation. Thanks for the reply.